# Combine snippet not working in function, how do I get this to work

Tags: swift, combine

I have two blocks of code, both similar.

One works in playground and performs as expected.

The other, when I make it part of a function (in an Xcode proj) does not work, and a very telltale warning from Xcode is that the 'immutable value of cancellableSink was never used'

I do not get that warning from Xcode when I execute this code in playgrounds. What is going on?

I have a feeling that my problem is not with Combine but something more fundamental

```
import Foundation
import Combine


let url = URL(string: "https://xkcd.com/614/info.0.json")



let publisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url!)
    .map{ $0.data }
    .decode(type: Joke.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .map { $0.img}

let cancellableSink = publisher
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        print(String(describing: completion))
    }, receiveValue: { value in
        print("Returned value: \(value)")
    })
```

**The code snippet above will work in playground** .. but why wouldn't this work in a Xcode proj inside of a function.

Below is a warning that I will get in a Xcode proj that I cannot repeat in playgrounds

[image: Text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create `let cancellableSink` in the function, so its scope is limited to this function. `cancellableSink` will be deallocated as soon as you go out of `myCompletionHandler`.

Instead, try to declare `cancellableSink` at the class / struct level, so it will be persisted *after* the function finishes.